# Resultant XML is blank with no data

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Im trying to create a xml output data which is as below
This is generated after passing cus_id=11 as parameter

```html
<data>
   <id>11</id>
   <count>2</count>
   <acres>148.48</acres>
    <no_of_orders_month>44</no_of_orders_month>
   <orders>7</orders>
</data>
```

All I need to do is pass in a parameter in the above output Im passing it as 11 I should get the above data in my result which I am not able to get it.There are few conditions on which I should be getting it here they are

1. custid should be the first element printed
2. The count of the orderstatus (meaning for cus_id=11 we have orderstatus 2 (1 for each time and cus_id is not unique in any scenario)).
3. The total  number of land area  which is the sum of land area for a given cus_id
4. For a particular cus_id it should calculate the sum of remaining numeric elements in this case it is no_of_orders_month and orders.

I have used the param and created the keys and using the sum and count function but the data is blank can anyone please provide inputs on how to correct my code to get the expected result.

Here is my xsl file which I tried custdetails.xsl

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:param name="cusid"/>
            <xsl:key name="data-by-customer" match="customer" use="@cusid" />
    <xsl:template match="customer">
        <xsl:variable name="abc" 
        select="key('data-by-customer', $cusid)" />
        <customer details="{$abc/cusid}" 
        count= "{count($abc/order_status)}" 
        landarea = "{sum($abc/land_area)}"  
        orders = "{sum($abc/orders)}"  
        number_of_orders="{sum($abc/no_of_orders_month)}"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is my xml file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customers>
    <customer>
        <cusid>11</cusid>
        <name>Maccarthy</name>
        <zip>45643</zip>
        <maritalstatus>married</maritalstatus>
        <gender>female</gender>
        <occupation>business</occupation>
        <orders>5</orders>
        <order_status>confirmed</order_status>
        <land_area>80.16</land_area>
        <no_of_orders_month>22</no_of_orders_month>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <cusid>33</cusid>
        <name>Jason</name>
        <zip>68978</zip>
        <maritalstatus>married</maritalstatus>
        <gender>male</gender>
        <occupation>Manager</occupation>
        <orders>4</orders>
        <order_status>not confirmed</order_status>
        <land_area>33.1</land_area>
        <no_of_orders_month>21</no_of_orders_month>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <cusid>42</cusid>
        <name>Sarah</name>
        <zip>76898</zip>
        <maritalstatus>single</maritalstatus>
        <gender>female</gender>
        <occupation>Homemaker</occupation>
        <orders>10</orders>
        <order_status>not confirmed</order_status>
        <land_area>21.4</land_area>
        <no_of_orders_month>9</no_of_orders_month>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <cusid>89</cusid>
        <name>Freddy</name>
        <zip>45643</zip>
        <maritalstatus>single</maritalstatus>
        <gender>male</gender>
        <occupation>mechanic</occupation>
        <orders>2</orders>
        <order_status>confirmed</order_status>
        <land_area>43.76</land_area>
        <no_of_orders_month>7</no_of_orders_month>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <cusid>87</cusid>
        <name>Nancy</name>
        <zip>34526</zip>
        <maritalstatus>single</maritalstatus>
        <gender>female</gender>
        <occupation>nurse</occupation>
        <orders>12</orders>
        <order_status>confirmed</order_status>
        <land_area>55.9</land_area>
        <no_of_orders_month>12</no_of_orders_month>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <cusid>87</cusid>
        <name>Martha</name>
        <zip>25789</zip>
        <maritalstatus>single</maritalstatus>
        <gender>female</gender>
        <occupation>nurse</occupation>
        <orders>2</orders>
        <order_status>not confirmed</order_status>
        <land_area>31.16</land_area>
        <no_of_orders_month>4</no_of_orders_month>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <cusid>11</cusid>
        <name>Brandy Johnson</name>
        <zip>78654</zip>
        <maritalstatus>married</maritalstatus>
        <gender>female</gender>
        <occupation>business</occupation>
        <orders>2</orders>
        <order_status>confirmed</order_status>
        <land_area>68.32</land_area>
        <no_of_orders_month>2</no_of_orders_month>
    </customer>
</customers>
```

Comment: This seems to be the same thing as your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70312927/im-trying-to-create-a-xsl-sheet-sum-and-count-function-doesnt-fetch-result-from

Comment: yes referencing that I implemented similarly can you please point out what's the mistake  because while compiling I don't find any errors as such.

Comment: It's a simple comparison, I don't think you need my help with that.